# how can i make a azure datafactory resource folder with python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory

Is it possible to create a folder with pipelines in data-factory using python?
was reading this tutorial:

[data-factory tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-python)

it creates a pipeline and just one copy activity
Can I create a folder so I can put the pipeline inside?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a folder before creating pipeline. Please see the sample code in your [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-python#full-script).

```
p_name = 'copyPipeline'
params_for_pipeline = {}
p_obj = PipelineResource(activities=[copy_activity], parameters=params_for_pipeline)
p = adf_client.pipelines.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, p_name, p_obj)
```

Deep into the `PipelineResource` 's parameters, you could find `PipelineFolder`.

[image]

So just add a param into above code.

```
folder = PipelineFolder(name="f1");
p_obj = PipelineResource(activities=[copy_activity], parameters=params_for_pipeline, folder=folder)
```

Comment: thanks i will give it a try, just waiting for some certifications =)

Comment: i am trying to import azure.mgmt.datafactory.models.pipeline_folder.PipelineFolder  so i can use it, but i get the error "no module named" ...   should i look for it in another import path?  thanks =)